# Flex Spark List not updating, missing items

Tags: apache-flex, list

I have a Spark.List with several items ("folders") each containing an ArrayList of files inside, when I select one of these "folders" it should display the list of "files" on another Spark.List. Its working right now by doing this:

```
private function onFolderChange (event:*):void {
    var list:List = event.currentTarget as List;

    if (list.selectedIndex != -1) {
        currentFolder = null;
        currentFolder = list.selectedItem;

        fileListDataProvider = currentFolder.files;
        fileList.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the "file" thumbnails cover more then the List viewport and a scroll is needed sometimes by changing from a "folder" to another "folder" the file List loses files.

For example lets say there is a "Folder 1" with 30 "files" in it (10 visible and 20 hidden by the scroller) and "Folder 2" has 5 "files" (all visible), if I switch back and forth between "folders" sometimes it will display everything right, sometimes it will display a scroll on "Folder 2" when there is no need and sometimes it will only display a few (5 or 10) "files" in "Folder 1" even though it has 30.

Something is wrong with the fileList, its updating its items but not really updating well. I've tried setting the itemRenderer to null and reapplying, setting the dataProvider to null and reapplying, doing validateNow().... I'm kinda lost.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use direct databinding?

```
<s:List id="folders" dataProvider="{folderList}" />
<s:List id="files" dataProvider="{folders.selectedItem?folders.selectedItem.files:null}" />
```

For your problem, try playing with `useVirtualLayout` or `updateDisplayList()`...

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain completely, I was trying to make the example simpler so that it would be easier to understand but in my case I can't use direct binding because I actually have 2 different folder lists so each has a changehandler that deselects the other and applies the dataprovider to the file list.

Comment: Ok :) What about the second part of my answer does it change things?

Comment: I tried useVirtualLayout but with no luck, as for updateDisplayList it doesn't seem to have that method. I think I might have fixed it now by adding a listener to the fileList.updateComplete event and in the handler setting the itemRenderer to null and then reapplying the itemRenderer, it seems that when there are a lot of files I have to wait for this event to be able to force it to render. Thanks for the help by the way.